# PDF CSS is not working in Laravel

Tags: laravel, pdf, dompdf, mpdf

I'm using this package for generating PDF.

https://github.com/praem90/laravel-mpdf

HTML is alright but CSS is loading and not working in PDF View.

Sometimes ERROR

A non-numeric value encountered

```
else {
$size *= (25.4 / $this->dpi); //nothing == px
}
```

in HTML view everything is OK problem in PDF view.

Comment: Are you sure `$this->dpi` has a value when the view renders?

Comment: $this->dpi = 96; // To interpret "px" pixel values in HTML/CSS (see img_dpi below)
// Automatically correct for tags where HTML specifies optional end tags e.g. P,LI,DD,TD
// If you are confident input html is valid XHTML, turning this off may make it more reliable

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the `$this->dpi` is a string with 'px' at the end. If that is the case, you can't do math with it. Store it as an int or double and then add the 'px' to it as needed, such as when rendering.